# Count number of columns in array php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple function to count numbers of columns with specific value in the array:

```
echo 'Status-accept: ' . array_count_values(array_column($array, 'status'))['Accept'];
```

it works well while `accept` exists in the array. If not I get `Undefined index: Accept`.
My array looks like that:

```
array{
...
["status"]=>
    string(7) "Accept"
...
}
```

How can I add something like `isset` here?

Comment: Why not add that? Is there any need to put all computation in a single line, and not split that up into several steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With oneliner is it not possible (or the code will be messy), so you have to store a value with counts somewhere and then use `??` operator for example:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'status'));
echo 'Status-accept: ' . ($counts['Accept'] ?? 0);
```

As a oneliner you can:

```
echo 'Status-accept: ' . count(array_filter($array, function($v) { return $v['status'] === 'Accept'; }));
```

Here we filter all items where status field is `'Accept'` and then just count filtered items. If there are no items - filtered array will be empty and we'll get `0` as result.